# Prove $α · β ≤ α · γ$ and $α^ β ≤ α^ γ$ for any three cardinals, where $ β ≤ γ$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, cardinals

This is what I did:

a. let $|A|=α, |B|=β, |C|=γ. |B|≤|C|$ and therefore there is an injection $f: B \to C$, such that $f(b)=c$ for some $b \in B, c \in C.$ Upgrading this function to $f'(a,b)=((id)a,f(b))=(a,c)$, we get an injection from $A\times B$ to $ A\times C$ proving $α · β ≤ α · γ$.

b. Knowing any function defines a unique set of ordered pairs of the form $(x,(f(x))$, the set of functions from $A$ to $B$ and $C$ to $B$ is equivalent to the set of possible sets of ordered pair of the form $(b,a)$ and $(c,a).$ Let $g:B \to A.$ Then $g$ can be written that way: $(b,g(b)).$ Now let us take a function $h: A^B \to A^C$ such that for every $g: B \to A, h(b,g(b))=(f(b),g(b)).$ This is of course an injection, proving $α^ β ≤ α^ γ. $

I would really like your corrections. Thanks.

Comment: The second inequality is false if $\alpha=\beta=0\lt\gamma$.

Comment: Then Both are zero, hence equal, which isn't false, is it not so?

Comment: $0^1=0$ but $0^0=1$.

Comment: Okay I see... Now I try to understand why my teachers would ask me to prove such a thing... But, regardless of it, how are my proofs?

Comment: Your proof of (a) looks OK, except that your injection $f'$ goes from $A\times B$ to $A\times C$, not from $|A\times B|$ to $|A\times C|$. I don't follow your argument for (b). If the domain of $h$ is supposed to be $A^B$ then for $g\in A^B$ you have to define $h(g)$, not $h(b,g(b))$. Basically, you have to show that every function $g:B\to A$ can be extended to a function $g':C\to A$. Which is easy to do if $A$ is nonempty.

Comment: @Meitar: It is often the case that whoever writes the exercises forgets about the trivial counterexample.

Comment: I really hope it was a mistake...
Because what bof points out is unequivocally true...